# Delete more than 6 million rows so SLOW

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, loops

I have a SP that needs to delete more than 6 million rows.

I tried this approach but still the execution time is SLOW.

```
DECLARE @continue BIT = 1

-- delete all ids not between starting and ending ids
WHILE @continue = 1
BEGIN

    SET @continue = 0

    DELETE top (10000) u
    FROM    Table1 u WITH (READPAST)
    WHERE       ID = @ID
    AND         NID IN (SELECT NID FROM #Node GROUP BY NID)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        SET @continue = 1 

end
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What means _slow_ exactly? How often do you need this SP?

Comment: disable delete triggers and all relationships before deleting and re-enable them after deleting. also, try using EXISTS or INNER JOIN rather then IN.

Comment: it takes more than an hour to process. everyday I need this SP to execute

Comment: Do you have a cascade delete on? Try smaller bathes i.e 1000 a time

Comment: If you need to delete 6 million rows every day I suspect something is terribly wrong in your database / application design.

Comment: did you check the execution plan so see which part takes time. how much data does your table have? what sort of indexes do you have. you need to provide more specifics

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table or any referencing tables?

Comment: Every time you start a transaction to delete 10'000 rows, a **lock escalation** will occur and the entire table will be exclusively locked. This can take it's time. Try using smaller batches, e.g. 1000 or 2000 (less than 5'000 which is the threshold for lock escalation)

Comment: Marc_s-Just try to delete less 1000 for every loop, the execution is still blocked. it takes longer hours

Comment: Check this out: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Answer (score 2):

Your loop logic looks OK

As other have said look at application design
Can you use staging tables and be able to truncate

If the table has FK and you are confident you are not going to violate them then disable the FK and re-enable

If you have a delete trigger and you need to delete 6 million every day then you really need to reevaluate the design

Look at optimizing the select then put it in the delete

```
select top (10000) u
  FROM Table1 u WITH (READPAST)
  JOIN #Node 
    on u.NIT = #Node.NIT 
   and u.ID = @ID
```

Comment: I don't have a delete trigger. Should it will be hassle if I enabled/disabled the FK's upon deleting?

Comment: Does it matter if I will change the condition to EXISTS?